# I can't find time zone tables in sys database of MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, timezone

For my Django application, I had to set the time zone to UTC, however I am not able to set it as I couldn't find any tables related to time zone in the system database.

How do I get those? the scripts available in here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html only relates to loading of data in the tables and not creating them.

- MySQL Version: 5.7
- OS: Windows

Comment: Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54044701/5293578

Answer (score 6):

I used to face the same issue as you and I resolved it by following these quick steps.

*Please follow below:*

Environment:

- MySQL Version: 5.7
- OS: Windows 10 (64 bit)

Steps:

- Download the package that contains the data files of pre-built time zone tables. You can download here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html

  - **timezone_2018e_posix_sql.zip - POSIX standard** for MySQL version **5.7**
- Extract the downloaded package, you will then have a file named **timezone_posix.sql**
- Open a command line in the **root** directory of MySQL. Ex: On my
  computer this is **"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"**
- Run the command `mysql -u root -p` to login to MySQL with root access and then enter password.
- Run the command `show databases;` to view all database. You will see a database named **mysql**. You need to insert data into the **mysql** database

  - Run the command `use mysql;`
- Finally, you can insert data by issuing the command `source *path timezone_posix.sql*`.

After inserting the timezone data, you can test by issuing the following query:

```
 SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-07-02 14:46:46','utc','America/Los_Angeles')
```

If the result is not null, you're successful!!!

Answer (score 1):

mysql_tzinfo_to_sql — Load the Time Zone Tables : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html
this might help you

Comment: Thanks gongsun, however my OS is windows so the above doesn't hold true for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows installations, see this page in MySQL documentation: [Time zone description tables](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html), where it states:

> This package contains time zone description tables which can be used with the MySQL server by users whose systems do not include zoneinfo files (e.g. Microsoft Windows, HP-UX).