# how do I insert timzone-pois.sql into MYSQL?

Tags: mysql-8.0

I have read about how to insert the time zone into MYSQL as below:

[I can't find time zone tables in sys database of MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149492/i-cant-find-time-zone-tables-in-sys-database-of-mysql/149501#149501)

However, after I type show databases, there was no response except showing mysql>

Thus I'd like to clarify how do I go about inserting the timzone-pois.sql into MYSQL.

I am using mysql workbench and mysql 8.0.13 server. Windows 10.
Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html), for Windows, you need to [download the timezones](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html) which is a zip file that contains a SQL file. This can be run in workbench.

Comment: The problem is I do not know where to port it to MYSQL server.  How do I run it ? Insert * from timezone-pois ?

Answer (score 0):

First download the file for 5.7+. Extract the zip file and navigate to unzipped folder from command prompt.

```
D:\MySQL_FILES>unzip timezone_2018g_posix_sql.zip
Archive:  timezone_2018g_posix_sql.zip
   creating: timezone_2018g_posix_sql/
  inflating: timezone_2018g_posix_sql/timezone_posix.sql

D:\MySQL_FILES>cd timezone_2018g_posix_sql

D:\MySQL_FILES\timezone_2018g_posix_sql>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ****
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 19
Server version: 8.0.13 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| employees          |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> use mysql;
Database changed
mysql> source timezone_posix.sql
```

After script completes successfully run some tests.

```
mysql> select sysdate();
+---------------------+
| sysdate()           |
+---------------------+
| 2018-12-21 17:07:28 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ(SYSDATE(),'utc','America/Los_Angeles') utc_la;
+---------------------+
| utc_la              |
+---------------------+
| 2018-12-21 09:07:35 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ(SYSDATE(),'utc','America/New_York') utc_ny;
+------------------------------------------------+
| utc_ny                                         |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 2018-12-21 12:07:41                            |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```